# Kendo Dropdown not retaining value when clicking on Inline Edit

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, dropdown, inline-editing

When I click on inline edit button, column titled "Industry" do not retain its value.

```
columns.Bound(c => c.IndustryName).Title("Industry").EditorTemplateName("AppPackIndEditor").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Extra(false).Operators(Operator => Operator.ForString(str => str.Clear().Contains("Contains")))).Width(120);
```

This is the code for the editor :

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AppPackIndEditor";
}

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
                  .Name("IndustryName")
                  .SelectedIndex(0)
                  .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
                  .DataTextField("IndustryName")
                  .DataValueField("IndustryId")
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;", required = "required", validationmessage = "Select Industry" })
                  .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Industry"])
                  .Events(x => x.Change("onChangeDropDown").Change("IndustryChange"))
                  .OptionLabel("--- Select ---")
                  .NoDataTemplateId("noDataTemplate")
                  )
```

I have tried renaming the property name etc but the issue still persists

Answer (score 0):

When using the `DropdownListFor(m=>m)` there is no need to set the `Name()` options. With the provided configuration the entire dataItem will be set as value for the IndustryName model property. Add the `ValuePrimitive(true)` so the value of the dataItem's field as set in the `DataValueField` is set as value of the `IndustryName` property. If the `IndustryName` is a string you can update the editor the following way:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
              .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
              .DataTextField("IndustryName")
              .DataValueField("IndustryName")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;", required = "required", validationmessage = "Select Industry" })
              .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Industry"])
              .Events(x => x.Change("onChangeDropDown").Change("IndustryChange"))
              .OptionLabel("--- Select ---")
              .NoDataTemplateId("noDataTemplate")
              )
```

Comment: Issue still persists